# How to update pipeline for a Deal using Bitrix24 API

Tags: javascript, rest, google-apps-script, bitrix

We've recently created two different pipelines for Deals inside Bitrix24.
Now we want to be able to move the existing deals from one pipeline to the other.

We'll be doing it using google apps scripts using REST calls (UrlFetchApp), which we are already using for other maintenance/routine tasks.
The documentation is rather obscure since it's not clear how to update this 'field' not how to list existing Deals.

Sample documentation:
https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/deals/crm_deal_list.php

There is no explanation of how to do it using REST calls.

E.g.: the following fails:
https://sysmanagement.bitrix24.com/rest/crm.deal.list.json?auth=(our_auth_token)
with error:

```
{"error":"insufficient_scope","error_description":""}
```

the above mentioned documentation doe not explain:

- how to interpret these error codes
- how to translate the Javascript example into REST calls
- expected attributes for the Deal object

can anyone provide (in order of decreasing preference):

- Google Apps Script to change the pipeline assigned to a Deal
- sequence of REST calls to change the pipeline assigned to a Deal

Comment: I just understood that the error code is due to insufficient scope while obtaining the oauth2 access_token, this does not however make me understand how to obtain the desired results

Comment: also: fields for the Deal object are documented here: https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/fields.php